# Covariant derivative of a scalar function

Tags: functions

How to write a covariant derivative on a scalar function in EDCRGTCcode.m package (https://faculty.washington.edu/lgy/ph564/): e.g. $\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi$;

Comment: Sorry, but editing the question to sneak in a second question, after the answer is accepted is highly inappropriate. I've shown you how to calculate covariant derivatives, but I'm not going to solve what seems like homework or a research problem for you. Bye

Comment: In the future please ask separate questions for separate problems. Also put in a bit of effort, not just copy pasting some pic with a bunch o complicated equations. You should always add your own code and specify what is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this, one is to note that the covariant derivative of a scalar field is indeed just a partial derivative. The other one is to just use the `covD[]` function of the package.

To illustrate in an example, let's define a coordinate system, a metric and run the package.

```
<< EDCRGTCcode.m

xCoord = {t, x, y, z};
g = {{-1,0,0,0},{0,a[t]^2,0,0},{0,0,a[t]^2,0},{0,0,0,a[t]^2}};
RGtensors[g, xCoord]
```

where I assumed cartesian coordinates and the flat Friedmann-Lemaitre-Robertson-Walker (FLRW) metric.

In this case, let's assume the scalar field on the background only depends on time (as otherwise would break homogeneity/isotropy), then we can calculate the covariant derivative as

```
covD[ϕ[t]]
(* {ϕ'[t], 0, 0, 0} *)
```

which as can be seen, is of course equal to `D[ϕ[t], {xCoord}]`.

Then the kinetic term $\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi$ can be found to be (by taking the dot product and contracting the indices properly)

```
multiDot[Raise[covD[ϕ[t]],{1}],covD[ϕ[t]], {1, 1}]
(* -\phi'(t)^2  *)
```

The covariant derivative of any scalar, vector or tensor field can be calculated similarly for any desired metric or coordinate system.